# Unity - can't detect OnPointerDown on a nested instantiated prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I dynamically create instance of a prefab - called Animal. And in some cases - I dynamically instantiate nested prefab inside the Animal - called Carrot.

Both Animal and Carrot implement `IPointerDownHandler` and have `OnPointerDown` methods:

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log("POINTER DOWN IN ANIMAL !!!" + data);
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log("POINTER DOWN IN CARROT !!!" + data);
}
```

However - the one in carrot never gets called. I always get the debug log from the Animal instance.

Any idea why I can't detect the pointer down on both so that I know if the user clicked/tapped the carrot or the animal that holds it?

Answer (score 0):

Is the carrot smaller or behind the animal object? The animal object may be blocking the raycast. [Look at this component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb2Xa.png)

The following may need to be set to false if you wish to interact with it given theyre overlapping [The component property in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7C3i.png)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Armin The carrot is not behind the animal and is not blocking anything. For the property you mentioned - I don't see such one on the animal or the carrot. Still - I was able to tackle the problem in another way - and I'll post an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day - the listener in the carrot didn't fire at all :( ... even if I remove the listener on the animal.

So - I ended up with converting the PointerEventData parameter data of the Animal listener into a world position and compare it with the transform.position of the Animal itself - and thus specify whether the user has tapped on the animal or on the carrot.

Dumb ... but working :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Physics Raycaster in Main Camera and you need to set Max Ray Intersections 0.

If you want click behind object, you can change Max Ray Intersections count.